# Last item Doubles result with RecordSet.FindNext

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
RS.FindFirst "[" & Me.CategTxtBx & "]='" & Me.SCSearch & "'"
If Not RS.NoMatch Then
   Call ListData 'displays the data on listbox row after row
End If

Do While Not RS.NoMatch
   RS.FindNext "[" & Me.CategTxtBx & "]='" & Me.SCSearch & "'"
   Call ListData 'display the data on listbox row after row
Loop
```

Above is my code for pulling all the data that matches the category and keyword the user will input.
Its working fine but the last data that will be found is always doubled. Can someone tell me why? I can't analyze the reason why.

I have a counter for found matches, so I need accurate count.

Comment: Has to be a better way to load a listbox. Why not set its RowSource property with SQL statement that includes filter criteria input by user?

Comment: Read on [debugging](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). What happens if`RS.FindNext`has no match?

Comment: Consider using `DCount` to get a count of found matches. Also, if you *really* need to open a recordset, rather than using `.FindFirst` and `.FindNext`, consider opening up a recordset that only has the required records in using ` WHERE`.

Comment: @June7 can you tell me how to do that? with my code as reference

Comment: `Me.comboboxname.RowSource = "SELECT fieldname1, fieldname2 FROM tablename WHERE [" & Me.CategTxtBx & "]='" & Me.SCSearch & "'"`

Comment: @June7 I tried what you said with this ```"SELECT * FROM " & dbVarName & " WHERE [BLOCK]='" & Me.SBlock & "' AND [LOT]='" & Me.SLot & "'"``` but it just display those exact phrases. And I was also using a loop to pull from different tables and stack them row by row in my listbox

Comment: Have to set RowSourceType to Table/Query, not ValueList. There is nothing in code that shows pulling from multiple tables. Why would you need to do that? Sounds like data structure is not normalized. A UNION query can merge records from multiple tables.

Comment: @June7 I'm creating a search form modal, a friendly GUI for users. Other tables are yearly record, I need to show all record history through my modal. Can I achieve that through UNION query? With user input on what needs to be searched? Also I tried setting it to Table/Query, now nothing shows

Comment: Your question is too broad and unfocused. Have not provided all relevant code. If you want to show all data from related tables then build query that joins tables. The result is likely not an editable recordset. Sounds like really need to run a report and apply filter criteria. Debug your code. Set breakpoint and step through execution.

Comment: If these multiple tables are not storing same type of data, a UNION is not appropriate. If you are trying to filter on any field from related records of multiple tables, that would be a JOIN query. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. So maybe an unbound form for user seletion of search criteria and apply to report.

Comment: @RichmonSantos Didyou at least discover your bug on`:RS.FindNext`? Yearly tables are bad design and now that causes pain;) Research on database normalization to learn how-to fix that. Did you try a simple`SELECT field1, field2 From YourTable`to populate the listbox? At last: seems like you missed the [tour] and reread [ask].

Comment: I'm so sorry if I'm missing out some rules here, its my first time dealing with access and only learned basic vb. Anyways I fixed it by putting another `if Not RS.Nomatch` on second `Call ListData`. Thank you very much for your time and help @June7. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding another If Not NoMatch statement inside the loop.

```
RS.FindFirst "[" & Me.CategTxtBx & "]='" & Me.SCSearch & "'"
If Not RS.NoMatch Then
   Call ListData 'displays the data on listbox row after row
End If

Do While Not RS.NoMatch
   RS.FindNext "[" & Me.CategTxtBx & "]='" & Me.SCSearch & "'"
   If Not RS.NoMatch Then
      Call ListData 'display the data on listbox row after row
   End If
Loop
```

I remember trying it but didn't work, but now its perfectly working.

Comment: Nice (ok, still room for improvement, but now it should be reliable), now I strongly recommend to fix the poor db design (normalization!) to avoid more pain from that! E.g. all tables that just differ in year should be imported to one table (same fields) with an addition field to store the year. Then you can create queries for each year by just adding`WHERE yearField = 2019`as criteria (by using a parameter for the year, one query can be used for all years!). Then it's simple to create a query that shows all data and bind it to the listbox as RowSource.